# How to connect table records with Dialog in Vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, modal-dialog, vue-component, vuetify.js

How to get dynamic data from tables in dialog in Vuetify. I have table with data

```
    <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.id }}</td>
    <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.title }}</td>
    <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.quantity }}</td>
    <td class="text-xs-left"> <Dialog :to="'/products/' + props.item.id"></Dialog></td>
```

and I have component Dialog.Vue.
How to connect to click to open a specific record in the dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dialog should be placed outside table. In table you should have button which trigger dialog. On example @click="dialog_visible = true" and if you need dynamic dialog you can set parameters for dialog in @click method.

Comment: <template slot="items" slot-scope="props" >
        
        <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.id }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.title }}</td>
        <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.quantity }}</td>
       <td class="text-xs-left" :id="props.item.id">
          <v-btn @click='dialog = true; fun($event.target.id)'  color="info" class="table- 
         btn" >Show Details</v-btn>
        </td>

  </template>



  This is my new code. I drop dialog tag and add @click listener. Just I need dynamic data from table

Comment: You can pass data as function parameter and sent it to dialog. Something like <button @click="openDialog(item)">Open Dialog</button> and then in openDialog function you can tell this.dialog_data = item and you can access selected element from dialog.